# how do i link listboxes throughout different forms

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

`I would like to Link Listboxes from one form to different other forms. For example if i were to add an item from another form that selected item will be shown throughout my other forms. is there any way to do this?

```
 private void pb_hd1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

        int index = hm_drinks.FindIndex(drinks => drinks.Name.Equals(hd1.Text));
        pendinglist.Items.Add("1 \t" + hm_drinks[index].Name.PadLeft(20) + hm_drinks[index].Price.ToString("C").PadLeft(70));
        order.Equals(pendinglist.Items);
        total += hm_drinks[index].Price;
 }
```

This is what adds the item to the list box but the item is only shown in this form's list box. I would like it to be shown in other forms to which is my problem at the moment.

Comment: Where's the code? I can't review the code without seeing it.

Comment: @PattonPierce i've edited the post with my only code to add to the listbox. I have no code placed in the list box at the momment

Answer (score 1):

You could store it in a variable of a [singleton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) object and read that value from form to form.

**Example Below**

Singleton Class:

```
public class MySingletonClass
{
    private static MySingletonClass _instance;        

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the singleton instance.
    /// </summary>
    public static MySingletonClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new MySingletonClass();
            }

            return _instance;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Property to be shared across application.
    /// </summary>
    public string MySharedProperty { get; set; }

    // Private default constructor
    private MySingletonClass() { }
}
```

Form 1 which has a text box and then a button to open form 2.  The button click event saves the textbox value to the singleton.:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void _openFormTwoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySingletonClass.Instance.MySharedProperty = textBox1.Text;

        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show();
    }
}
```

Form 2 which has a textbox.  It loads the value from the singleton instance:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        textBox1.Text = MySingletonClass.Instance.MySharedProperty;
    }
}
```

Comment: would you be able to show me an example ? thank you for you answer

Comment: Thank you for your example! Just asking, if i want to add an item instead of just a property how would i change the code?

Comment: You can just add a List as a property to your singleton class.